# gunicorn error while running python script

Tags: python, gunicorn, aiohttp

Here is my python code.

```
    from aiohttp import web

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = web.Application()
        cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app)

        app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)
        app.router.add_get("/", index)
        app.router.add_get("/client.js", javascript)

        cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app, defaults={
            "*": aiohttp_cors.ResourceOptions(
                    allow_credentials=True,
                    expose_headers="*",
                    allow_headers="*",
                )
        })
        resource = cors.add(app.router.add_resource("/offer"))
        cors.add(resource.add_route("POST", offer))

        resource = cors.add(app.router.add_resource("/image_makeup"))
        cors.add(resource.add_route("POST", image_makeup))
        
        web.run_app(
            app, access_log=None, host=args.host, port=args.port, ssl_context=ssl_context
        )
```

Command:

```
gunicorn main:app --bind localhost:8080 --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker
```

error:

```
    [2020-10-17 21:17:13 +0530] [47676] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
    [2020-10-17 21:17:13 +0530] [47676] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (47676)
    [2020-10-17 21:17:13 +0530] [47676] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    [2020-10-17 21:17:13 +0530] [47678] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47678
    usage: gunicorn [-h] [--cert-file CERT_FILE] [--key-file KEY_FILE] [--host HOST] [--port PORT] [--verbose]
    gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --bind localhost:8080 wsgi:main
    [2020-10-17 21:17:18 +0530] [47678] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 47678)
    [2020-10-17 21:17:19 +0530] [47680] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47680
```

I have main.py inside my root directory still m getting above error.
Please have a look where i am making the mistake.

Comment: i updated the error please check

Answer (score 0):

As you are not running directly your file "main.py", the value of the variable `__name__` is not `__main__` but `main`. You need to change your `if` statement :

```
if __name__ == "main":
    app = web.Application()
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, Pierre i updated my my question with different error. Please take a look. Getting another error

Comment: Did you update your command line `gunicorn main:app --bind localhost:8080 --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker` from the previous error?

Answer (score 0):

As given [in the documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html#nginx-gunicorn),

When running Gunicorn, you provide the name of the module, in your case `main`, and the name of the app or application factory, along with other Gunicorn Settings provided as command line flags or in your config file.

The entry point could be either an application instance or a coroutine that accepts no parameters and returns an application instance

Your Code has to be like:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def my_web_app():
    app = web.Application()
    ....
    return app
```

or

```
from aiohttp import web

my_web_app = web.Application()
....
```

Gunicorn command becomes:

```
gunicorn main:my_web_app --bind localhost:8080 --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker
```